# Which books reveal these spoilers in Wheel Of Time?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

A friend of mine is working his way through the WOT series for the first time. I read it several years ago and want to discuss a couple of things with him but don’t want to give spoilers by asking him "Has x been revealed?"

I am hoping someone can remind me which early books reveal the following points so I can wait till he has finished that book before discussing it:

- Before the time of breaking the world was technologically far more advanced and the “magic” was technology. I think this is revealed in book 3 or 4.
- The Aiel originally followed the way of the leaf.
- > Rand’s heritage (Mum an Aiel).
- Asmodean death. (Can’t wait to see who he thinks killed him.)

Comment: This question seems rather broad at the moment with you asking multiple questions in one question. Can you only ask one per question. Side note if you think the detail is a spoiler you can use the markdown `>!` to hide it

Comment: It just has four bullet points. Although I have no idea about wheel of time, I'd expect an answer with four numbers ranging from 0 to 14 to be enough. It is not too broad.

Comment: @C.Koca So how is 4 questions not too broad? Your logic seems a bit odd.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I have seen more than once that if two of those bullet points are covered in the same book, it may be closed as duplicate due to answers being the same. Had him asked four separate questions, he would only flood the questions tab, either receiving less attention or reducing visibility of other questions.

Comment: @C.Koca Yes but he doesn't know what book they're in so that logic doesn't hold. Also they are asking about something different so would not be duplicates. Flooding the questions isn't a bad thing and the OP could give time between each question too. A too broad question is still too broad even if you don't want to "flood the questions tab".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot My WWII influence in LotR question was closed twice because some WWI influence question mentioned WWII, so although it is incorrect use of duplicate, there are many people who would tag it so, just because of the answer. Besides, this question can be perfectly answered using four numbers and they are all connected due to (probably) being milestones in the same series. Anyway, if this question gets shut, I'll be casting the first open vote :)

Comment: @C.Koca One bad closure does not mean all questions are going to be closed poorly though I don't know the example you are talking about. Feel free to use your privileges how you see fit but I don't think your interpretation of the rules is correct in this case. We shall see what others think.

Comment: I would stick the spoilers into 4 different questions.

Comment: @C.Koca - The issue is that one person might know the answer to bullet point 1 only, and answer that; while someone else might know the answer to 2 and 4, and a third person the answer to 3. If the OP gets those three answers, which one is correct? All three are correct and necessary, but you can only select one answer. By splitting the points into separate questions, all answers could be appropriately awarded. (In this particular case, as two answers were given, both of which responded to all points, and one has been accepted, the issue is moot now, but it's still the right way in general).

Comment: @RDFozz Actually the question asks the max(book(x), x in bullets). So it is definitely one question. But even if it weren't, I would still consider it as a single question. The third person would learn the rest and present it as an acceptable answer. It is a very short and exhaustive list. Good answers usually require some research on the answerer's part as well. Also, again, there are many people here who upholds wrong standards for duplicate policy and had they been different questions, they would be marked duplicate if they had occurred in the same book.

Comment: @C.Koca - I read it as the OP wants to be able to discuss 4 things, and being able to discuss one after the friend reads book 4 even if others couldn't be discussed until after book 6 would be ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asmodean dies at the very end of [**Fires of Heaven**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fires_of_Heaven), the fifth book.  [Who killed Asmodean](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Who_killed_Asmodean%3F) is never officially explained outside a glossary entry in [**Towers of Midnight**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towers_of_Midnight), the thirteenth book.

As the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/185029/30870) stated, the advanced society and the Aiel following the Way of the Leaf becomes obvious after Rand travels to Rhuidean in [**The Shadow Rising**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow_Rising), the fourth book.

The part you have in spoiler markup is incorrect:

> Rand's mother was not an Aiel; his father was.  His mother was [Tigraine](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Tigraine_Mantear) from Andor, Daughter-Heir of the previous queen.  Galad is his half brother.

He knows about this in **[Lord of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_Chaos)**, the sixth book, but really all the clues were there earlier.

So once your friend reads the sixth book, you can talk about any of these with impunity.  You can talk about the history of the Aiel or the Age of Legends after the fourth book.  You can talk about Asmodean's death after the fifth book.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed :), no idea why i had Rands mum being Aiel in my head. Thinking about it I knew she wasn't :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the books with me,but if memory serves all of these except Asmodeans death are revealed when Rand goes to Rhuidean in book 4.

The last isn't revealed until very late in the series, and it's done in kind of an offhand way, I honestly can't remember.